# how can i create a grainy rough plastic material in blender, just like one on MI TV Remote

Tags: texturing, objects, shaders

I am creating a tv remote and for that, I am looking for material just like MI tv remote.

[image: material what i am looking for]

Answer (score 5):

It looks like basically, for plastic, you need to mix a *Diffuse* with a *Glossy*.

To make it more realistic, use a *Fresnel* in the *Factor* of your *Mix Shader* so that the light will enlight the contour of your object a bit. You can also add a second mix to add a *Translucent* shader so that the light plays a bit more naturally with the object thickness.

Your object also have a grainy surface, so you need to add some noise: Use a *Noise Texture* that you plug into a *Bump* node that you plug into your shaders *Normal* sockets. As the details are very small, choose a high *Scale* in the *Noise Texture*.

[image]

Comment: Maybe using Principled instead of Fresnel + Mix + Diffuse + Glossy is a bit easier but it should work with your solution as well

Comment: sure, I didn't try with the Principled, I'm a bit old school